# Minimizing the repeated code in js

Tags: javascript

I have a calculator functionality in JavaScript using simple functions as follows:

```js
function add() {
    var a = parseInt(document.getElementById("num1").value);
    var b = parseInt(document.getElementById("num2").value);

    var result = a + b;
    document.getElementById("result").value = result;
}

function subtract() {
    var a = parseInt(document.getElementById("num1").value);
    var b = parseInt(document.getElementById("num2").value);

    var result = a - b;
    document.getElementById("result").value = result;
}

function multiply() {
    var a = parseInt(document.getElementById("num1").value);
    var b = parseInt(document.getElementById("num2").value);

    var result = a * b;
    document.getElementById("result").value = result;
}


function divide() {
    var a = parseInt(document.getElementById("num1").value);
    var b = parseInt(document.getElementById("num2").value);

    var result = a / b;
    document.getElementById("result").value = result;
}

function clearr() {
    document.getElementById("num1").value = "";
    document.getElementById("num2").value = "";
    document.getElementById("result").value = "";
}
```

```html
<span style="margin-right:1px">Number 1 </span>
 <input id="num1" type="number"  ></br>
 <span style="margin-right:5px" >Number 2</span><input id="num2" type="number" ></br>
<span style="margin-right:29px">Result</span><input id="result" type="number"> </br>


<button id="add" onclick="add()">+</button>
<button id="subtract" onclick="subtract()">-</button>
<button id="multiply" onclick="multiply()">*</button>
<button id="divide" onclick="divide()">/</button>
<button id="clear" onclick="clearr()">clear</button>
```

However there is a lot of repeated code. Is there any other way to solve this problem without getting repeated values of a and b each time.

Comment: You could make a function to get `a` and `b` and then call that in each method. P.S you're br's should be like this `<br/>`

Comment: Define a + b at the top of the code and just pass it in to each function

Comment: nice but i expect a single function to accomplish all tasks and return all the  operations

Comment: I believe this question fits better at [cr.se](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use one function passing operation name, than check it with `if`/`switch`. To clear all, just pass in non-existing operation:

```js
function action(method) {
  var a = parseInt(document.getElementById("num1").value);
  var b = parseInt(document.getElementById("num2").value);
  var result = null;

  switch (method) {
    case 'add':
      result = a + b;

      break;
    case 'subtract':
      result = a - b;
      break;
    case 'multiply':
      result = a * b;
      break;
    case 'divide':
      if (b != 0) {
        result = a / b;
      } else {
        alert('Can\'t divide by 0');

        return;
      }

      break;
  }

  if (result !== null) {

    document.getElementById("result").value = result;
  } else {

    document.getElementById("num1").value = "";
    document.getElementById("num2").value = "";
    document.getElementById("result").value = "";
  }
}
```

```html
<span style="margin-right:1px">Number 1 </span>
<input id="num1" type="number"></br>
<span style="margin-right:5px">Number 2</span><input id="num2" type="number"></br>
<span style="margin-right:29px">Result</span><input id="result" type="number"> </br>


<button id="add" onclick="action('add')">+</button>
<button id="subtract" onclick="action('subtract')">-</button>
<button id="multiply" onclick="action('multiply')">*</button>
<button id="divide" onclick="action('divide')">/</button>
<button id="clear" onclick="action('clear')">clear</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can optimize and clean your code as below:

```
var num1 = document.getElementById("num1");
var num2 = document.getElementById("num2");
var result = document.getElementById("result");

function add(){
    result.value = parseInt(num1.value) + parseInt(num2.value);
}

function subtract(){
    result.value = parseInt(num1.value) - parseInt(num2.value);
}

function multiply(){
    result.value = parseInt(num1.value) * parseInt(num2.value);
}


 function divide(){
     result.value = parseInt(num1.value) / parseInt(num2.value);
 }

 function clear(){
     num1.value = "";
     num2.value = "";
     result.value = "";
 }
```

if you want a single function. You can write the following function:

```
 function PerformCalculation(calType){

     var num1 = document.getElementById("num1");
     var num2 = document.getElementById("num2");
     var result = document.getElementById("result");         

     switch(calType) {
         case 1:
             result.value = parseInt(num1.value) + parseInt(num2.value);
             break;
         case 2:
             result.value = parseInt(num1.value) - parseInt(num2.value);
             break;
         case 3:
             result.value = parseInt(num1.value) * parseInt(num2.value);
             break;
         case 4:
             result.value = parseInt(num1.value) / parseInt(num2.value);
             break;
        default:
            result.value ="";
            num1.value = "";
            num2.value = ""; 
    }  
 }
```

Call calType 1 to this function on the click of add button, 2 on the click of substract button, 3 on the multiplication button and 4 on the division button. Pass any other number to clear it. Your HTML will be like the following:

```
<button id="add" onclick="PerformCalculation(1)">+</button>
<button id="subtract" onclick="PerformCalculation(2)">-</button>
<button id="multiply" onclick="PerformCalculation(3">*</button>
<button id="divide" onclick="PerformCalculation(4)">/</button>
<button id="clear" onclick="PerformCalculation(0)">clear</button>
```

Comment: Its right but I need a single function which will return values of all the operations

Comment: I've updated  my answer for both ways. Only one single function and multiple functions...You can use whatever the way you like

Answer (score 1):

Some [higher-order functions](http://eloquentjavascript.net/05_higher_order.html) should help you here.

```js
var ids = ['num1', 'num2', 'result'];

function getVal (id) {
    return parseInt(document.getElementById(id).value);
}

function setVal (id, result) {
    document.getElementById(id).value = result;
}

function setCalc(func) {
    setVal(ids[2], func(getVal(ids[0]), getVal(ids[1])));
}

function clearAll () {
    ids.map(function(id) {setVal(id, '');});
}

function add (a, b) {return a + b;}
function subtract (a, b) {return a - b;}
function multiply (a, b) {return a * b;}
function divide (a, b) {return a / b;}
```

```html
<span style="margin-right:1px">Number 1 </span>
 <input id="num1" type="number"  ></br>
 <span style="margin-right:5px" >Number 2</span><input id="num2" type="number" ></br>
<span style="margin-right:29px">Result</span><input id="result" type="number"> </br>

<button id="add" onclick="setCalc(add);">+</button>
<button id="subtract" onclick="setCalc(subtract);">-</button>
<button id="multiply" onclick="setCalc(multiply);">*</button>
<button id="divide" onclick="setCalc(divide);">/</button>
<button id="clear" onclick="clearAll();">clear</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following custom function:

```
function doOperation(type) {
    var a_el = document.getElementById("num1"),
        b_el = document.getElementById("num2"),
        a = parseInt(a_el.value),
        b = parseInt(b_el.value),
        result = document.getElementById("result");

    switch (type) {
        case '+':
            result.value = a + b;
            break;
        case '-':
            result.value = a - b;
            break;
        case '*':
            result.value = a * b;
            break;
        case '/':
            result.value = a / b;
            break;
        default:
            a_el.value = '';
            b_el.value = '';
            result.value = '';
            break;
    }    
}
```

Usage:

```
doOperation('*'); // multiplication
doOperation(); // clearing
```

Comment: Where is `clear()`? Returning 0 does not clears element. **After edit**: no matter what your `type` is, your cases missing `break` so only final `default` will be executed

Answer (score 0):

```
const utilsConfig = {
            numOne: parseInt(document.getElementById("num1").innerText),
            numTwo: parseInt(document.getElementById("num2").innerText),
            result : document.getElementById("result"),
            maths: function (func) {
               this.result.innerText = this[func]();
            },
            add: function () {
              return this.numOne + this.numTwo;
            },
            subtract: function () {
              return this.numOne - this.numTwo;
            },
            multiply: function () {
              return this.numOne * this.numTwo;
            },
            divide:function () {
              return this.numOne / this.numTwo;
            },
            clearr: function () {
              this.numOne.innerText = 0;
              this.numTwo.innerText = 0;
              return 0;
            }
        }
```

Comment: You still have code repetition in every function, you just wrap it in variable.

Comment: I have created multiple functions to separate the functionality.

Comment: @Justinas : utilsConfig.Math  will call all the functions automatically .

Answer (score 0):

You can define a single function and pass the button itself as the parameter, then do the calculation according to the button id.

```js
 function doCalc(btn) {
        var a = parseInt(document.getElementById("num1").value);
        var b = parseInt(document.getElementById("num2").value);
        var result = 0;
    
        if(btn.id == 'add'){
            result = a + b;       
        }else if(btn.id == 'subtract'){
            result = a - b;
        }else if(btn.id == 'multiply'){
            result = a * b;
        }else if(btn.id == 'divide'){
            result = a / b;
        }else{
            alert("Action undefined");
            return;
        }
        
        document.getElementById("result").value = result;
    }
    
    function clearr() {
        document.getElementById("num1").value = "";
        document.getElementById("num2").value = "";
        document.getElementById("result").value = "";
    }
```

```html
    
    <span style="margin-right:1px">Number 1 </span>
    <input id="num1" type="number"  ></br>
    <span style="margin-right:5px" >Number 2</span><input id="num2" type="number" ></br>
    <span style="margin-right:29px">Result</span><input id="result" type="number"> </br>
    
    
    <button id="add" onclick="doCalc(this)">+</button>
    <button id="subtract" onclick="doCalc(this)">-</button>
    <button id="multiply" onclick="doCalc(this)">*</button>
    <button id="divide" onclick="doCalc(this)">/</button>
    <button id="clear" onclick="clearr()">clear</button>
```